# Youtube-api very small quotas by using access token

Tags: youtube

I registered in the google console, created my project and enabled youtube api v3.
I uploaded videos from a server, I did it via Oauth2 (from my account). I confirmed it for the first time, received a refresh token and now just update the access token to upload the video.

The problem is in quotas: I read that youtube provides a quota of 1,000,000 (one million) units per day, to download a video to spend + -1600, but for some reason I have a limit of 3,000,000 (three million), BUT at the same time 10,000 is written per day . And ten thousand - this is 6 videos of all.
Could you explain to me what all the quotas are and why I only have 10,000 per day?
In the first screenshot, we can see that only 11,184 units out of 3,000,000 were spent.
and on the second that almost the entire limit was spent (almost 10,000)

*I want to upload video from the server to YouTube automatically.
Through my user.

[first screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTzRz.png)
[second screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkndK.png)